# Can I use Enterprise LIbrary while developing Windows application and how?

Tags: windows, enterprise-library

Can I use Enterprise library while developing Windows application and how?

Comment: Can you be a little more specific like what are you trying to do.  What type of application.

Answer (score 0):

Suggest you download and run the samples.